# SQLite optimization -- two databases vs. one

Tags: iphone, sqlite, optimization, multiple-databases

I'm developing an iPhone app with two SQLite databases.  I'm wondering if I should be using only one.

The first database has a dozen small tables (each having four or five INTEGER or TEXT columns).  Most of the tables have only a few dozen rows, but one table will have several thousand rows of "Items."  The tables are all related so they have many joins between them.

The second database contains only one table.  It has a BLOB column with one row related to some of the "Items" from the first database (photos of the items).  These BLOBs are only used in a small part of the program, so they are rarely attached or joined with the first database (rows can be fetched easily without joins).

The first database file size will be about a megabyte; the db with the BLOBs will be much larger -- about 50 megabytes.  I separated the BLOBs because I wanted to be able to backup the smaller database without having to carry the BLOBs, too.  I also thought separating the BLOBs might improve performance for the smaller tables, but I'm not sure.

What are the pros and cons of having two databases (SQLIte databases in particular ) to separate the BLOBs, vs. having just one database with a table full of very narrow tables mixed in with the table of BLOBs?

Answer (score 1):

Even at 50 MB, that is a very small database size, and you're not going to see a performance difference due to the size of the database itself.

However, if you think performance is the issue, check your DB queries, and make sure you're not 'SELECT'ing the BLOB rows in queries where you don't need that information. Returning more  rows from the database than you need (think of it as reading more data from a hard drive than you need to), is where you're much more likely to see performance issues.

I don't see any pros to separating them, unless you are under a very tight restriction on the total size of the backup. It's just going to add complexity in weird places in your app.